# Python saving file

Tags: python

I am trying to write and save a file but the following error is raised by the python script:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Export/ixxxx/izzzzz_2015-05-12 17:00:00.shp
```

What is wrong with the path? The directory exists.

Comment: That isn't a valid file name.

Comment: @Ajay - You can certainly use `/` in a pathname in Windows in a Python script.

Comment: @Ajay: Windows can cope with forward slashes in pathnames, but it has problems with colons. Also using backslashes as path separators brings its own problems. Backslashes in a plain string should be backslash-escaped. Alternatively, the path can be given as a raw string, although a raw string can't have a backslash as the final char.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't allowed to use colons in file names in Windows (which I'm guessing is what you're using given the rest of the path). There is a bit more information [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: Solved. Windows... That was all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can have a colon immediately after the volume name (`C:`), but not anywhere else in the path.  You'll need to replace the colons with another character.  I would use the `-` character, to keep it consistent with your date format.  As a matter of personal preference, I would probably also replace the space in the filename with a `-`.

See the following example:

```
>>> pathname = 'C:/Temp'  # Change this to your pathname.
>>> filename = 'izzzzz_2015-05-12 17:00:00.shp'
>>> filename = filename.replace(':', '-').replace(' ', '-')
>>> print('{}/{}'.format(pathname, filename))
C:/Temp/izzzzz_2015-05-12-17-00-00.shp
>>> with open('{}/{}'.format(pathname, filename), 'w') as f:
...     pass
...
>>>
```